# TypeError: 'replaceState' called on an object that does not implement interface History

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm looking at this snippet of javascript code

```
if (history) {
    var action = settings.replaceState ? history.replaceState : history.pushState;
    if (action) {
        // next line throws the error
        action(null, null, window.location.pathname + window.location.search + '#' + hash);
    }
}
```

settings.replaceState == true

Microsoft's latest thing gives me this

> Invalid calling object

In Chrome the same piece of code throws this

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

and I get this error in Firefox

> TypeError: 'replaceState' called on an object that does not implement interface History.

When I debug the history looks as it should and there is a prototype containing this method in it.

Aside from the different error messages can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You lost the execution context of `history` by assigning the method to a variable. You need to set the execution context back to `history` by using [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
action.call(history,null, null, 
            window.location.pathname + window.location.search + '#' + hash);
```